# 'shinydashboard' is not showing item properly in 'sidebar'

Tags: shiny

I have created a Shiny App using Package 'shinydashboard' as below :

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
              menuItem("ABC", tabName="ABC", icon=icon("line-chart"), selected=TRUE),
              menuItem("ABC1", tabName="ABC1", icon=icon("line-chart"), selected=FALSE)
  ),
 conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC'",
    fluidRow(
        column(11, offset = 1, h5((' Note')))
      )
    ),
 conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC1'",
    fluidRow(
        column(11, offset = 1, style = "height:20px; color:rgb(30,144,255);", h1((' Update')))
      )
    ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC",br())

    ),
    tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC1",br())

    )
  )


ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "ABC"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server = function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However I have noticed a strange behaviour that, when I run the App, initially the comment 'Note' in "input.tabs == 'ABC'" is not visible. However when I click on "input.tabs == 'ABC1'" and then 'ABC', the 'Note' comment becomes visible.

Can somebody points me where I went wrong in above code?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Everything works for me. I'm on `shiny` version 1.0.3 and `shinydashboard` version 0.5.3

Comment: Hi, I am using latest version of both Shiny & shinydashboard, as below. > packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘1.0.3’
> packageVersion('shinydashboard')
[1] ‘0.6.0’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we introduced this bug in the newest version of `shinydashboard`. Sorry! I'll try to fix it soon. You can keep track of the progress here: https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/214.

**Update (9 June 2017):** This is now fixed on the development version of shinydashboard. Your original code should run just fine if you install shinydashboard from github:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/shinydashboard")
```

---

In the meantime, a couple of things:

- You don't need to use `selected = FALSE`.
- If the `menuItem()` that you want to start selected is the first one (like in the example you posted above), also remove `selected = TRUE` and your problem goes away. This is just a workaround to get your app working now. When this bug is solved, there will be no difference in having `selected = TRUE` or nothing in the first `menuItem()`.
- A more general workaround for now (works no matter which `menuItem()` you want to start selected) is to use a dynamic sidebar menu:

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenuOutput("menu"),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC'",
    fluidRow(
      column(11, offset = 1, h5((' Note')))
    )
  ),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'ABC1'",
    fluidRow(
      column(11, offset = 1, style = "height:20px; color:rgb(30,144,255);", h1((' Update')))
    )
  ))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC",br())

  ),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "ABC1",br())

  )
)


ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "ABC"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server = function(input, output){
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
      menuItem("ABC", tabName="ABC", icon=icon("line-chart"), selected=TRUE),
      menuItem("ABC1", tabName="ABC1", icon=icon("line-chart"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```